# MockMvc: Forwarded URL expected:</WEB-INF/views/layout.vm> but was:<null>

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, velocity, matcher, mockmvc

I have the below Velocity config for both test and main in my spring mvc app:

```
@Bean
public VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig(){
    VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig = new VelocityConfigurer();
    velocityConfig.setResourceLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
    return velocityConfig;
}

@Bean
public VelocityLayoutViewResolver viewResolver(){
    VelocityLayoutViewResolver viewResolver = new VelocityLayoutViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setCache(true);
    viewResolver.setLayoutUrl("layout.vm");
    viewResolver.setPrefix("");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".vm");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

It works correctly when I deploy the WAR and all my `MockMvcResultMatchers` in test except for `forwardedUrl which returns null:

```
@Test
public void testHome() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("index"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/views/layout.vm"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("myData", Matchers.is(Matchers.not(Matchers.empty()))));
```

The appropriate Controller under test has the following beginning:

```
@RequestMapping({"/index", "/"})
public ModelAndView home(){
```

The stacktrace begins:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Forwarded URL expected:</WEB-INF/views/layout.vm> but was:<null>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers$1.match(MockMvcResultMatchers.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:152)
    at com...
```

Why is the forwarded URL incorrect? Is it an issue with the MockMvc or the velocity setup?

Comment: where are mapping `/` to `layout.vm`?

Comment: default spring mvc behaviour I believe - see a comment on an earlier question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936650/error-org-apache-velocity-resourcemanager-unable-to-find-resource-layout-vm#comment59542084_35937701

Comment: Here is same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782970/mockmvc-forwardedurl-is-null)

Comment: that is not the same issue as mine